# Haml/Ruby/Rails adding an element conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, haml

I have this code:

```
- userlist.each do |member|
  = render :partial => 'projects/member_small', :locals => { :user => member }
```

And I want to add a div element every two times do |member| occurs. So basically every two times. I want this:

```
- userlist.each do |member|
  .row
    = render :partial => 'projects/member_small', :locals => { :user => member }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could slice the list into groups of two:

```
- userlist.each_slice(2) do |group|
  .row
    - group.each do |member|
      = render :partial => 'projects/member_small', :locals => { :user => member }
```